# Any way to make a transparent Keynote background?

Tags: keynote, animation

Longtime Keynote user, and I'm starting to turn many of my Keynotes into movies that I can drop into Screenflow (a video editing app). I'm doing a lot of animated text instruction videos, and wondering if there's a way to create a keynote that has a clear transparent background, so that if I add other images into the Screenflow timeline, they can appear in the background of the Keynote movie. I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I wanted to ask. Adding text into Screenflow is 10x slower than Keynote. Keynote really is the best text animator I've found for videos.

Answer (score 1):

Screenflow supports Chroma Key, to automatically remove the background of your video.

1. In your Keynote presentation, open the Format inspector and choose Edit Master Slide.
2. For each master slide in use, set the slide background to green, then choose Done.

   [image]
3. When you import your Keynote video into Screenflow, select the video and under Video Properties, add a Video Filter for Chroma Key.

   - [Screenflow - Using Chroma Key](https://vimeo.com/168418791)

Comment: @user Welcome to Ask Different! If an answer solved your problem, you can mark it accepted using the check mark under the voting buttons on the left, thanks